# How do I account for covariates after doing a mann whitney test?

Tags: regression, logistic, ordinal-data, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, predictor

So I have ordinal data that is marked as strongly agree, agree, neither agree nor disagree, disagree and strongly disagree and two different groups which I am comparing. I have used a mann whitney to see if the groups are significantly different. Now I would like to see if this difference is still significant when adjusting for age, gender and BMI. Do I use ordinal logistic regression to adjust for these covariates?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  When the dependent variable is ordinal, ordinal logistic regression is often appropriate.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/152805)

Comment: The question was whether to use ordinal logistic.  The answer is "yes".

Comment: Questions that have purely "yes" or "no" answers typically are considered off-topic on SE, Peter.  We can make them on topic by providing more expansive answers than specifically requested.  I believe that is the point @kjetil was trying to make.

Comment: OK, but then should this question be deleted?  It sure seems like a statistics question, and it also seems like "Yes" is a full answer.